# Prove that $P \times P$ is countably infinite

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, infinity

$P$ is the set of prime numbers and I may assume that there are infinitely many prime numbers. My first thought was using an infinite grid but the question is only $2$ marks and I think I have spotted an easier method using the assumption stated in the question. I know that $P \subset N$, and we know that $N$ is countably infinite since there exists a bijection $f: N \to N$.

By the lemma for any sets $X$ and $Y$ with $X \subset Y$, we have $|X| \leq |Y|$, I now have $|P| \leq |N|$, but since $P$ is an infinite set, then we must have $|P| \geq |N|$. So in all, $|P|=|N|$, which means $P$ is countably infinite since it has the same cardinality as $N$.

Comment: It's a subset of $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ which is countable as the Cartesian product of two countable sets, so $P \times P$ is at most countably infinite, and is clearly not finite (e.g. consider the elements $(p, 2)$ for $p$ a prime, which are all distinct and for which there are infinitely many given your assumption that there are infinitely many primes)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Sorry I had a brain-freeze, please ignore my post. Sorry about that. I will edit it.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Could I then add on to my argument above that since I have proven that $P$ is countably infinite, and I know from a lemma that the cartesian product of  finitely many countable sets are countable, then $P \times P$ must also be countably, and we know it must be countably infinite since it's clearly not finite.

Comment: Yes, you can. Proving the product is countable is basically a diagonalization argument.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Yeah I think I like this argument because it's easier to explain than using an infinite grid. If I wanted to, could I use an infinite grid only including primes and use a similar argument to $N \times N$ ? Because the grid would show a clear bijection from $N$ to $P \times P$

Comment: Sure. Label each prime with an integer in order (2 is the first prime so it gets 1, 3 is the second prime so it gets 2, etc). Let $f$ be the function mapping the primes to integers. Then the induced map $g$ given by $g(p, q) := (f(p), f(q))$ will be an isomorphism. Geometrically, this is just collapsing the prime lattice down to the integer lattice using the map $f$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Can you check my answer below to see if this method works as well. I'd like to be comfortable in multiple ways. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The right hand side shows how the elements of this grid may be labelled with elements of $N$, by
proceeding down each diagonal in turn from top left to bottom right. This creates a bijection from $N$ to $P \times P$,
namely the function $f : P \to P \times P$ in which each $n \in N$ in the right hand grid maps to the pair $(a, b)$ in the
corresponding position in the left hand grid. $f$
is well-defined since every natural number appears once in the right hand grid and so is mapped to exactly
one pair in the left-hand grid; $f$ is injective and surjective since each pair appears precisely once in the
left-hand grid so is mapped to by exactly one element of $N$. The existence of this bijection proves that
$P \times P$ is countably infinite

Comment: Yes, this is a good proof. (it's precisely what I was alluding to in the comment about a diagonalization proof). Well done!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks for your help today - happy new year : )

Comment: No problem, and a happy new year to you as well!